# É possível obter timestamps com precisão de frações de milissegundos?

Tags: javascript

Tenho que calcular o tempo de execução de uma função javascript, tenho meu código pronto e funcionando, meu único problema é o limite do `getMilliseconds()` que só vai até **999** e a execução do método é extremamente rápido, então precisaria de mais casas.

Código do `getTime()` e do `tempoExecucao()`: http://pastebin.com/P9Cv6wzt

Alguém saberia uma solução para isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, obrigado pela ajuda galera, com a ideia de vocês conseguir formular o seguinte:

Peguei o com `var tempoInicio = getTime();` o inicio da execução e com `var tempoFim = getTime();` o fim do mesmo.

```
// Pega tempo
function getTime(){
    var horaInicio      = new Date();
    var minutos         = horaInicio.getMinutes();
    var segundos        = horaInicio.getSeconds();
    var milisegundos    = horaInicio.getMilliseconds();
    var arrTempo = [minutos, segundos, milisegundos];
    var tempo = arrTempo.join();
    return tempo;
}
```

Com os 2 dados de inicio e fim, envio por parâmetro para o tratamento do tempo na seguinte função:

```
// Calcula Tempo de Execução
function tempoExecucao(tempoInicio, tempoFim){
    var tempoInicioCalc = tempoInicio.split(",");
    var tempoFinalCalc = tempoFim.split(",");
    // calculo do tempo
    var calcMinuto          = tempoFinalCalc[0]-tempoInicioCalc[0];
    var calcSegundo         = tempoFinalCalc[1]-tempoInicioCalc[1];
    var calcMilisegundos    = tempoFinalCalc[2]-tempoInicioCalc[2];
    // une em uma array
    var tempoCalc = [calcMinuto, calcSegundo, calcMilisegundos];
    // une em uma string
    tempoCalc.join();
    return tempoCalc;
}
```

Porém ele terá um pequeno problema no ms pois a soma poderá dar valores negativos, entao implementando essa função para complementar.

```
function trataTempoNegativo(trataTempo){
    if(trataTempo[2] < 0){
        var tratadoTempo= [];
        tratadoTempo[0] = trataTempo[0];
        tratadoTempo[1] = trataTempo[1];
        tratadoTempo[2] = trataTempo[2]+1000;
        return tratadoTempo;
    }
    return trataTempo;
}
```

Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Mas isso não dá uma precisão maior que a dos milissegundos! Não era isso que você queria?

Answer (score 9):

### Temporizador de performance

É possível sim, obter timestamps com precisão de frações de milissegundos.
Os navegadores modernos permitem usar temporizadores de performance:

```
window.performance.now()
```

Ao medir o tempo inicial e final com este método, você terá muito mais precisão. O valor retornado é um float, que mede milissegundos, mas possui a parte fracionária, portanto permite medir com precisão abaixo dos milissegundos.

```js
var inicio = window.performance.now();
// medindo o tempo do for, iterando 1 milhão de vezes
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {}
document.write(window.performance.now() - inicio);
```

### [jsfiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/nF8ch/)

**Conheça mais sobre este recurso**

- [When milliseconds are not enough: performance.now()](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now) <sup>(inglês)</sup>: artigo do html5rocks explicando como funciona e a diferença para o tipo `Date`.
- [Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) <sup>(inglês)</sup>: Documentação na MDN.
- [A better timer for JavaScript](http://gent.ilcore.com/2012/06/better-timer-for-javascript.html) <sup>(inglês)</sup>: este artigo tem considerações importantes sobre o uso de `performance.now`, pois alguns navegadores adicionam um prefixo no nome da função:

  ```
   performance.now
   performance.mozNow
   performance.msNow
   performance.oNow
   performance.webkitNow
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, achei essa função que é uma tentativa de implementação do microtime do PHP em Javascript, tenta dar uma olhada:

```
function microtime(get_as_float) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/microtime/
  // original by: Paulo Freitas
  //   example 1: timeStamp = microtime(true);
  //   example 1: timeStamp > 1000000000 && timeStamp < 2000000000
  //   returns 1: true

  var now = new Date()
    .getTime() / 1000;
  var s = parseInt(now, 10);

  return (get_as_float) ? now : (Math.round((now - s) * 1000) / 1000) + ' ' + s;
}
```

fonte: https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/datetime/microtime.js