# Verificar o tempo de execução de uma função Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, runtime

Gostaria de saber se é possível saber o tempo de duração de execução de uma determinada função javascript..

Essa função não precisa trazer dados externos, pode apenas lidar com tags de formulário, setar valor, calcular campos, como esse:

```
function idade(ano_aniversario, mes_aniversario, dia_aniversario) {
var d = new Date,
    ano_atual = d.getFullYear(),
    mes_atual = d.getMonth() + 1,
    dia_atual = d.getDate(),

    ano_aniversario = +ano_aniversario,
    mes_aniversario = +mes_aniversario,
    dia_aniversario = +dia_aniversario,

    quantos_anos = ano_atual - ano_aniversario;

if (mes_atual < mes_aniversario || mes_atual == mes_aniversario && dia_atual < dia_aniversario) {
    quantos_anos--;
}

return quantos_anos < 0 ? 0 : quantos_anos }
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10660/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-obter-timestamps-com-precis%C3%A3o-de-fra%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-milissegundos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Conforme já disse o colega Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10662/74), nos navegadores modernos você pode medir o tempo decorrido com precisão de frações de milissegundos, usando o objeto [`performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance). A lógica é a mesma das outras respostas, mas para não ficar repetitivo vou sugerir uma função genérica que mede o tempo de execução de qualquer outra função que for passada (exceto operações assíncronas):

```js
// Passe a função desejada. Se ela esperar parâmetros,
// passe os parâmetros na sequência. Exemplo:
// tempoDecorrido(minhaFuncao, 1, true, {teste:10});
function tempoDecorrido(funcao) {
    // pega os argumentos a serem repassados
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    // logo antes da execução
    var inicio = performance.now();

    // executa a função passada, passando os argumentos se for o caso
    funcao.apply(null, args);

    // logo após a execução
    return performance.now() - inicio;
}

// Faz um loop de x a x+9
function minhaFuncao(x) {
    for(var i=x; i<x+10; i++) console.log(i);
}

// Testando
console.log(tempoDecorrido(minhaFuncao, 10));
```

Comment: Boa, torna-se mais simples medir a execução sem ter que mesclar o "medidor" no código da função a ser analisada.

Comment: Acho essa solução mais interessante pois assim não é necessário repetir o código de cálculo da duração em todas as funções, bastando apenas chamar a função tempoDecorrido quando e se for necessário. Isso  significa também que as funções já existentes não precisarão ser modificadas para calcular suas durações.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode capturar o tempo de início do seu método e ir removendo o tempo que passou do tempo atual até o final da execução:

```
function seuMetodo()
{

var start = new Date();

for (var i=0; i<=30; i++) {
       console.log('mostra: '+i);
 }
var time = new Date() - start;
return 'tempo: '+time;
} 
seuMetodo();
```

Answer (score 3):

Para registar o tempo de execução, basta registar o começo e o fim dentro da tua função alvo.

Com JavaScript podes fazer uso do método [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) do objeto `Date()`, cujo mesmo te devolve o valor numérico correspondente ao tempo para a data especificada de acordo com a hora universal.

```js
function tempoDecorrido() {

  var fim = new Date().getTime();

  var tempo = fim - inicio;

  alert('Tempo de execução: ' + tempo);
}


var inicio;

function idade() {

  inicio = new Date().getTime();

  /* a função deve ser chamada no fim da "idade", 
   * mas aqui chamamos após 1 segundo, para simular
   * que estivemos a trabalhar durante esse tempo
   */
  setTimeout(tempoDecorrido, 1000);
}

idade();
```